# How to mock with RhinoMock in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, mocking, rhino-mocks, rhino

I can't found any relevant info regarding how to use RhinoMock in Silverlight.
I didn't event find Rhino Mocks for Silverlight. Standard Rhino Mocks pack doesn't include Silverlight edition. I saw that there is some DynamicProxy, but couldn't get it also.

Could anybody clarify how to use RhinoMock with Silverlight?

Answer (score 2):

Rhino Mocks doesn't have a Silverlight version.  You'll need to use something like [NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.com/) (compile from source at the moment), [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/), [FakeItEasy](http://code.google.com/p/fakeiteasy/) or one of the other mocking frameworks that has a Silverlight version